# Keras Tuner throws InvalidArgumentError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss

I'm trying to use Keras Tuner to test different configurations and hyperparameters of my neural net 
I have code that works when running outside the tuner (but I have to run it with eager execution disabled),
 but inside the tuner, I get an exception thrown. I'm new to using more complicated neural networks, so I'm trying to wade through the documentation but I get lost sometimes.
Hers' the custom_loss and model plus tuner code

```
def custom_loss(yardline):
yardline=K.cumsum(yardline)
def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true=K.cumsum(y_true)
    y_pred= y_pred*yardline
    new_total_prob= K.sum(y_pred)
    inverse_prob=K.pow(new_total_prob+K.epsilon(), -1)
    y_pred= y_pred*inverse_prob
    cdf_pred= K.cumsum(y_pred)
    return K.mean(K.square(y_true-cdf_pred))
return loss
```

Here's the model

```
def build_model(hp):
input_layer= Input(179,)
yardline=Input(199,)
x=Dense(32)(input_layer)
for i in range(hp.Int('num_layers', 2,4, default=4)):
    x= Dense(units=hp.Int('units_' + str(i),
                                        min_value=32,
                                        max_value=512,
                                        step=32),
                           activation='relu')(x)
    if (i==3 or i==5):
           x=Dropout(hp.Choice('dropout_'+ str(i),[0.15,0.25]))(x)
output_layer = Dense(199, activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(inputs=[input_layer, yardline], outputs=output_layer)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=custom_loss(yardline), metrics=['accuracy'])
return model
```

Here's the tuner code

```
tuner = kt.Hyperband(
    hypermodel=build_model,
    objective='val_accuracy',
    max_epochs=5,
    factor=2,
    hyperband_iterations=3,
    distribution_strategy=tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(),
    directory='.',
    project_name='project')
tuner.search([X_train,yardline_train],y_train,
         epochs=5, batch_size=43,
         validation_data=([X_val, yardline_val],y_val))
```

Any help appreciated
The error says in particular Invalid Argument Error: and expects data into `input_2`...

 Again just seems strange since it ran when I loaded model without the tuner

Comment: I believe the problem comes from the fact that you have 2 Inputs.  
Your `yardline=Input(199,)` is not used in your model, but still you give it to your loss function, there is something wrong with this. Why do you have 2 different inputs ?

Comment: I added it as input so I could pass it to loss function, it has to be inside the model for it to be passed into the loss, or is there another way to do it?

Comment: @JamiePickett Any update on this? I have a similar issue with a custom loss using two inputs. Thanks!

Comment: @hhh I had kind of put this aside and not looked at it in a while, but no I never really got it to work out through keras tuner how I had hoped... I will try to dig through the documentation again and re try it soon

Comment: @JamiePickett Thanks! I think the issue comes when there are more than a single input: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/508